# Select query Locks the table, why does this happen

Tags: php, mysql, performance, join

I have a MyISAM table as I work with MATCH AGAINST and I have a select query which locks the entire table. Why does it happen?

Here is some output:

[image]

Comment: Unrelated - but what program are you using to generate that output?

Comment: seems like show full processlist

Comment: That is `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` and `phpMyAdmin`'s Processes tab

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html

Comment: I've came across of that, but select queries could cause locks?

Comment: Yes, there are locks by read operations as well. They have a lower priority than locks by write operations, but they exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this question, [Any way to select without causing locking in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917640/any-way-to-select-without-causing-locking-in-mysql) may help you out. It appears to be locking because it's a MyISAM table.

Comment: That's true, but I need the full text indexes.

Answer (score 1):

MyISAM is "table level locking", meaning that the table can handle only one query at the time.
So, as @Drazisil told, you have few options: optimize your query to reduce locking problem - stop using MySQL plain text feature (which is very poor performance) - split your big query into smaller queries - improve your indexes OR switch to innodb which is "row level locking"