# mysql - Long query execute time locks table

Tags: mysql, database

I have a mysql database which collects data from all kinds of resources.
In order to show some statistics from different tables, I run a long query which takes about a couple of minutes to execute.
The query locks some tables and therefore I can't write to these tables.
The tables are InnoDB engine.  I tried several options including:
1. Increasing the lock timeout
2. Adding `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;` and `COMMIT;` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917640/any-way-to-select-without-causing-locking-in-mysql))
3. Adding indexes to the tables (made the query run faster, but I still get a lock timeout error)

How can I execute the long query without locking the tables?

Comment: and what is the query?

Comment: It's a bunch of SELECT's, JOIN's, SUM's and more...

Comment: Are you sure there's a lock? Please `SHOW PROCESSLIST` and `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`. Selects do not lock anything. But they might *be waiting* for locks to be released

Comment: try running the set of query's that updates the table in a different transactions than the one that just retrive's them

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

From the comments in [Any way to select without causing locking in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917640/any-way-to-select-without-causing-locking-in-mysql) :

> Setting "set session transaction isolation level read committed;" did not help.
>
> Setting "set session transaction isolation level read uncommitted;" did not help.
>
> Using lock tables on either side did not help.
>
> Setting innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1 in my.cnf fixes the problem, but I guess the downside is that now I will not be able to use replication in this database.

If you don't need replication, then I would try that.

Comment: no idea if this will work.  I've never had an issue with locking, and I tend to stay out of my.cnf as much as possible.  Good luck!