# JSON from mysql not display properly through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

This is my database of mysql on the web

[This is my database on the web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUr8l.png)

This is the PHP file to access the database to get a JSON file, first I select all the "category" cell in the table, then loop through the category, and then loop through the other columns of a category, and assign to an array of $data2, after that assign $data2 and category to br an array of $data, which is the json I want to display.

```
<?php 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$user = "u348833238_rest"; /* User */
$password = "a!23286029"; /* Password */
$dbname = "u348833238_rest"; /* Database name */
$host = "localhost";

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$con) {
 die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
} 

// $sel = mysqli_query($con,"select * from restaurant");

// $data = array();

// while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sel)) {
//  $data[] = array("dishes" => ["name"=>$row['food'], "price"=>$row['price']] , "category"=>$row['category']);
// }
// echo json_encode($data);


$sel = mysqli_query($con,"select distinct category from restaurant");

$data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sel)) {

    $c = $row['category'];

    $sel2 = mysqli_query($con,"select * from restaurant where category = $c ");

    $data2 = array();

    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sel2)){
        $data2[] = array("name"=>$row2['food'], "price"=>$row2['price']);
    }

    // echo $data2;

    $data[] = array("category"=>$row['category'], "dishes"=>$data2);
}

// echo $data;
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

How the JSON is not displayed properly as the array of property "dishes" is empty as below:

[the array is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4CPf.png)

Comment: I advice you to read about preventing [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Don't do iterated queries.  Use a JOIN.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Where exactly do you think the vulnerability is in posted query?

Comment: I don't see it.  Be more specific.  What makes you think that `$c` is a threat?  Are you concerning yourself with potential 2nd-stage injection where user-supplied data is previously inserted into the `restaurant` table?  This extends too far into tinfoil hat territory to be making an assumption.  We have no reason to believe that the table is corrupted based on the posted details.

Comment: using a PHP variable directly in the query @mickmackusa when using a database always use prepared statements **no exceptions** even if you think the input/data is "safe".. Indeed stored SQL injections can be possible if the user has access to the `restaurant` table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql)  ...and many, many others.

Comment: Also closable with: [MySQL query in a loop vs using a SQL join](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18404913/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’d recommend turning errors on so you can see where the problem is.

At a guess it’s here:

```
select * from restaurant where category = $c
```

Should be:

```
select * from restaurant where category = '$c'
```

Comment: i wonder why you didn't even mention the SQL injection in your answer which is possible..

Comment: @RaymondNijland There are considerable problems yes, but I’m guessing this is not a serious project. They’ve also posted what looks like actual MySQL data in their example too, so there’s only so much one can do.

Comment: "so there’s only so much one can do. "  True well the problem of internet is that bad things/tutorials/answers keep around and can be found for decades. This is a pretty populair website for (starting) programmers at least warn the (starting) programmers for dangerous unsafe code more people are doing this..

Comment: @ThomasEdwards This low-hanging fruit question is a duplicate.