# MYSQL - Using SUM

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find the top 10 authors who has written the most number of books.

I have two table as follows:

**Author table:**

```
author_name
publisher_key
```

**Publication table:**

```
publisher_id
publisher_key
title
year
pageno
```

To find the result, I tried using the following query:

```
SELECT a.author_name, SUM(p.pageno)
FROM author a JOIN publication p ON a.publisher_key = p.publisher_key
GROUP BY a.author_name
LIMIT 10;
```

I have no idea why when I run this query it takes ages though the number of records is only 200.

Comment: So is your question about why the query is taking so long?  How many records do the `authored` and `publication` tables have?

Comment: Is the table name `author` or `authored`?  You use them both

Comment: I have 200 records in publication and for the authored table there is only 20 records.  It seems to be going into an infinite loop. My question is that I cant seem to get a result from the above query.

Comment: Seem it's rather a locking problem.

Comment: how do i fix a locking problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is as ydoow suggested that it maybe a locking issue, try running your select with NOLOCK to confirm.

```
SELECT a.author_name, count(*)
  FROM author a WITH (nolock)
       INNER JOIN publication p WITH (nolock) ON a.publisher_key = p.publisher_key
  GROUP BY a.author_name 
  ORDER BY 2 desc
  LIMIT 10;
```

You can get more info here:
[Any way to select without causing locking in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917640/any-way-to-select-without-causing-locking-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT a.author_name, count(*)
  FROM author a 
       INNER JOIN publication p ON a.publisher_key = p.publisher_key
  GROUP BY a.author_name 
  ORDER BY 2 desc
  LIMIT 10;
```

You want to know who write most number of books, so you need to count the number of registries by author.

The `order by 2 desc` will order your query from the bigger number to the lesser `2` means the second field on the select list.

Comment: Hi i tried the sql query but it still's go into an infinite loop. I am just curious what does this do "GROUP BY 2 desc" ?

Comment: @windboy It was a typo, I already corrected it. `ORDER BY 2 desc` there is also an explanation for it