# MySql: Do I need to commit SET SESSION TRANSACTION?

Tags: mysql, transactions

I had problems using

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp AS (SELECT * FROM mytable);
```

because I got very much deadlocks. Now I use:

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp AS (SELECT * FROM mytable);
```

which produces no deadlocks so far, but I want to know if I can use it this way or if I have to commit this:

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp AS (SELECT * FROM mytable);
COMMIT;
```

I saw some code with COMMIT at the end and code without COMMIT so I'm not sure if SET SESSION TRANSACTION also starts a transaction or not.

Answer (score 0):

The use  DDL statements implies  an implicit autocomit  eg:   your

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp AS (SELECT * FROM mytable);
```

see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html for more

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry, I don't get it: I have AUTO_COMMIT=1, but as soon as I use START TRANSACTION, the autocommit is disabled till ROLLBACK or COMMIT. The Q is if SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED; starts an transaction as START TRANSACTION does, because I found code ending an SET SESSION TRANSACTION with COMMIT (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33926532/get-uncommitted-data-in-mysql for example).

Comment: The use of `create  table ..`   involves commit .