# Cloning live table on a production

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an online store with table 'Orders' and I want to clone/copy this table with every record to a new one - but the problem is that each moment table 'Orders' is being updated by customers... so simplest solution 'INSERT (...) SELECT (...)' wont work (cause during this time, new records will be added)

Has anyone ever tried it ? Does anyone have any idea how to achieve it ?

Comment: What do you mean by "won't work"?  Do you get an error?

Comment: How big is the DB? How often does this DB get insertions to the table? Have you taken a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3280042/1305745)?

Comment: @wallyk : - nope. Read carefully - "during this time, new records will be added"

Comment: @ cavpollo : really huge, so avery second multiple record are added - thats why my problem exists

Comment: seems like a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917640/any-way-to-select-without-causing-locking-in-mysql

Comment: @ David Cram: show me where cause what u have posted is completely out of my question